# How can I allow donor to edit the amount to pay towards his Invoice

Tags: contribution-page, invoice

I am sending the donor a link to his dashboard where he can click Pay here to pay an outstanding invoice.

The issue is that once he clicks 'Pay Now' he is forced to pay the total amount of the invoice (Or pending contribution) and cannot edit the amount and make a smaller payment towards his balance due.

Is there a way to allow the donor to edit the amount?
Also why are the the words (includes of $0.00) after the amount?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Also why are the the words (includes of $0.00) after the amount?

I suspect because your site has the Tax/Invoice option turned on but it has not been fully set up